# break sentence with regular express in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to break the following string:

```
1. This is first 2. This is 45. second 3. This is third
```

using regular expression:

```
question = Regex.Split(strText, @" [0-9]+\. ");
```

It comes out like:

```
1. This is first 
2. This is 
45. second 
3. This is third
```

Where as i want like:

```
1. This is first 
2. This is 45. second 
3. This is third
```

Actually I want to break string with numbers from 1. to 30. If any other digit comes in the sentence statement it should not be broken.
How can I tackle this string to get the above result?

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://regexr.com?2vlfb):

```
Regex.Split(strText, @"\b([0-2]?[1-9]|30)\.");
```

---

**Update**

The regex is correct for matching numbers between 1 to 30 followed by a dot as delimiters, the problem is the `Regex.Split()` behavior. I think you can't get what you want with `Regex.Split()` in one step.
   Use `Regex.Replace` and `String.Split()`:

```
question = Regex.Replace(strText, @"(\b([0-2]?[1-9]|30)\.)", System.Environment.NewLine + "$1").Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/IVM84413

Comment: It works but it gives out like: question[0] = 1, question[1] = This is first and so on...